# Changing default on hover behavoir of image in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css

I have an image which is disabled, for which, on hover it should be normal 'pointer' and when enabled it be a 'hand' This works fine in IE
But in FF the default behavior, on hover is a 'hand', even when the image is disabled. 
How do i change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.selector:disabled').live('hover', function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','default');
}
$('.selector').not(':disabled').live('hover', function() {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
}
```

This is a jquery way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

CSS should do the trick

```
img {
     cursor:pointer;
}
```